# cplex: Setting the EPGAP not zero but upper bound and lower bound are the same

Tags: cplex

I know when I set the EpGap zero, upper bound and lower bound are the same and the solution is best. But, when I set the EpGap not zero, why are upper bound and lower bound also the same?

Comment: Now I need to record the upper bound and lower bound when I set the EpGap not zero. I think they shouldn't be the same. But when I set the EpGap not zero, the upper bound and lower bound are the same. Why?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the [EpGap](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpAGap.html) (aka, "relative MIP gap tolerance") parameter, we have the following:

> When the value `|bestbound-bestinteger|/(1e-10+|bestinteger|)` **falls**
>   **below** the value of this parameter, the mixed integer optimization is
>   stopped. For example, to instruct CPLEX to stop as soon as it has
>   found a feasible integer solution proved to be within five percent of
>   optimal, set the relative MIP gap tolerance to 0.05.

As soon as CPLEX finds a solution that is better than what is specified by the gap, the optimization is stopped and that's what you get (it could even be optimal).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of EpGap. Now I need to record the upper bound and lower bound when I set the EpGap not zero. I think they shouldn't be the same. But when I set the EpGap not zero, the upper bound and lower bound are the same. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the mistake of thinking that by setting EpGap to zero you will always get a better solution. What setting the EpGap parameter to zero means is that you are asking CPLEX to **prove** that there is no possible better solution

CPLEX is built and set by default to try to find good solutions early in the search process. I have seen many cases where it has found the optimal solution in a few seconds for even quite large problems that are well-structured, but it might then take hours to search the rest of the B&B tree to prove that there is no better solution and reduce the gap to (close to) zero.

Other than in a few quite specific circumstances, setting EpGap to zero is almost always a **bad** idea.

You may have a small well-structured mathematical problem based on precise and certain data, and in such cases it can work OK. I am thinking about abstract problems in mathematics or theoretical physics for example.

However, most real-world applications using CPLEX (or any other similar solver) are working with forecasts and measurements which cannot be known precisely with any degree of certainty. Think about e.g. a blending problem (e.g. making alloys, foods) where a gap of 1e-6 means that the solution is optimal at the level of about 1 gramme variation per tonne of material. Or for a transport problem, we know the distances between sites to be visited which may be many kilometres apart are correct to the nearest centimetre or so. Travel and working times would be known to accuracies of one-tenth of a second per day. Basically, think about what your numbers actually mean, and don't be seduced by spurious precision. In many domains, having 5% error in forecasts is considered very good.

You may still want to prove a solution is near optimal to e.g. 0.1% gap even in such cases, but trying to find a provably optimal solution to a zero gap for an approximate problem is probably pointless in practice.

Also many real-world problems are large, with thousands or millions of variables. In such cases, asking CPLEX to prove optimality to a zero MIP gap could take days or years.

Comment: Now I need to record the upper bound and lower bound when I set the EpGap not zero. I think they shouldn't be the same. But when I set the EpGap not zero, the upper bound and lower bound are the same. Why?

Comment: For any given problem instance (or with any particular solver, or any of a number of different scenarios) you *may* get the upper and lower bound being the same and have a gap of zero, even if you do not ask the solver to find a proven optimal solution. Typically the solver (e.g. CPLEX, Gurobi, Xpress) will stop when the gap between the best solution objective value and the best bound is less than the tolerance. Zero is certainly less than any positive tolerance. You may just be lucky that with your problem the solver finds the optimal solution and proves it optimal 'by accident'